# Unable to dynamically add dropdown menu through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

It may sound trivial but I am unable to do it.

Here is the simple code : what's wrong I am doing here ?

Is it like I have misunderstood the function? If yes, please correct me.

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>                             
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".button").click(function(){
        jQuery('#id').append('<select></select>');
       });     
      });
   </script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="id" value="submit"/>
  </body>
```

Comment: where do you expect the `select` to be placed? you have to provide a valid selector for an element in the page

Comment: where is an element with id on your page?

Comment: What do you means by #id in the code.Provide valid id to append dropdown

Comment: Your code is not working because you are trying to insert the select in your input element. Create a new <div id="select-list" container and append your select to it.

Comment: @alex yes that was the actual problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering your own code you can simply write

```
$('#id').after('<select></select>');
```

generally append works with a container since #id is associated with a button so it will not work. use div/span if you still want to use append, but if you don't want to .after() works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have no container/element in your body that will hold the newly added `select`, add a container in your html like this with `id="id"`

```
<body >
     <div id="id">
     </div>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit"/>
</body>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RwvQd/)

Answer (score 1):

Does `#id` exists in the document?

Do you want to add `<option>` to `<select>` ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        jQuery('body').append('<select><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option></select>');
    });
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XVmuZ/

If you want to add it to `#id` then make sure it exists (like in rahul's answer)

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XVmuZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

fisrt thing don't use submit button because it will postback your page so jquery will not work.
try this code

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>                             
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".button").click(function(){
        $('#ddl').append('<select><option>abc</option><option>def</option></select>');
       });     
      });
   </script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <input type="button" class="button" id="id" value="submit"/>
    <div id="ddl">
    </div>
  </body>
```